# Why are my variables "undefined"

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I am new to Javascript and I am building my very first simple game "battle ship". Now I have a very frustrating problem.

I declared a variable in the global scope, but I cannot seem to use it in my program. If I do console.log(x);      it says the variable is undefined.

When the user clicks a button called "Play" I want the background color of all cells to turn back to lightblue again;

```
function playGame() {
  x.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
}
```

This is the error message:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined

Even if I would replace the x with document.getElementsByTagName("td"); it does not work

```
var tabel = document.getElementById("slagveld");
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
var gekozenVakken = [];
var hit = 0;
var pogingen = 0;

function reset() {
    location.reload();
}

function veranderKleur(geklikteCel) {
  if (gekozenVakken.length < 3) {
        geklikteCel.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
        gekozenVakken.push(parseInt(geklikteCel.innerHTML));
    }
    if (gekozenVakken.length === 3) {
         alert("guess the position of the ship.");
      }
}

function playGame() {
  geklikteCel.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
}


for (var i = 0; i < tabel.rows.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < tabel.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
        tabel.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function() {
            veranderKleur(this);
        }
    };
}
```

I hope someone could help me out.

Comment: [`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns a list of elements

Comment: Sound like your script is running before the page has been fully loaded. Either place your script at the end of the page or call it by a window.onload function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetElementsByTagName()` returns an array of objects, even if there is only 1 object with that tag. Since the array itself does not have the property .style, you get an 'undefined' message when accessing sub-members of .style.

You need to select an element from that array to access its properties:

```
x[0].style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
```

With the `[]` square braces you can access any element of an array. In my example, we're accessing the first element (at index 0). Which element you need is up for you to determine.

Comment: Thank you very much. By explaining that the array itself does not have these properties, I now understand I need to select elements within the array to alter properties. :)

Answer (score 0):

That function returns a list of nodes, even though there's only one

use   `document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].style.color= 'lightblue';`

```
function playGame() {
  x[0].style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
}
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rexha3o7/)**

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now. Steenbergh gave me also a good explanation; I now understand why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If the line

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
```

is before your `<table>`, that element won't exist when the line is executed.

Ensure you are adding your script at the end of your HTML document or it will return an empty  **array** (please note that the function is called "get element**s** by tag name", in plural).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes; a typo is easily made. The script tag is at the end of the body.                                                                              <div id="score">
    <button onclick="playGame()">Play Game</button>
    <button onclick="reset()">RESET</button>
    
    </div>
        <script src="program.js"></script>
    </body>

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're running this in your browser and this is your entire code.
Problem here: You're trying to read content from the DOM, however, your DOM might not be entirely loaded at the time you try to read from it.

This is easily fixable though:
In your HTML:

```
<body onload="start();"></body>
```

And in your JS code:

```
function reset() {
    location.reload();
}

function veranderKleur(geklikteCel) {
  if (gekozenVakken.length < 3) {
        geklikteCel.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
        gekozenVakken.push(parseInt(geklikteCel.innerHTML));
    }
    if (gekozenVakken.length === 3) {
         alert("guess the position of the ship.");
      }
}

function playGame() {
  geklikteCel.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
}

function start() {
  var tabel = document.getElementById("slagveld");
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  var gekozenVakken = [];
  var hit = 0;
  var pogingen = 0;


  for (var i = 0; i < tabel.rows.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < tabel.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
          tabel.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function() {
              veranderKleur(this);
          }
      };
  }
}
```

This will ensure that all your reading/executing will perform when the entire DOM was loaded.

If you're not running code in your browser, please give more details in your question.

Comment: This is the _pure JavaScript_ way of doing it. @Harry-Detsis provided another answer which depends on JQuery (Also, my choice of Framework if I had to take on ;p).

Comment: Thanks guys; the variables are now defined :)

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it's because the code for initializing the variables never actually gets called. Try doing it as follows (you need jQuery for it):

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var tabel = document.getElementById("slagveld");
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    var gekozenVakken = [];
    var hit = 0;
    var pogingen = 0;
});
```

This way as soon as your DOM is loaded into the browser the variables will get initialized.

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByTagName return a list of elements with the name "td" and you don't have the property backgroundColor for the list of elements, you must use a function like foreach.

```
       Array.prototype.forEach.call(x, function(el, i){
           el.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
       });
```

And each element will in "x" will have the background color yellow.

Answer (score -2):

You're looking for [document.getElementById](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp)